# What can cause argon2_elixir to have a problem loading during test

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Looking for help/hindsight  on an error I get when running one of my controller test.
This is my first umbrella project so I might have botched or forgotten something.

I have 3 Apps:

- DB (ecto)
- Context (UserManager, SessionManager...)
- Web (Controllers, View, basically the phoenix stuff)

The test causing the problem:

```
test "With valid data, a new user is created and returned", %{conn: conn} do
  conn = post(conn, Routes.user_path(conn, :create), user: @valid_user)
  assert %{"email": "test_user_name@email.com", "id": 1, "name": "TestName", "username": "TestUserName"} = json_response(conn, 200)
end
```

This action (UserController.create/2 ) ends-up calling the context app which in turn will call the db app. Inside the db app the password of the user is hashed using Argon2. When I use postman to test my API everything works. But when I try to do it using integration test, I get an error with Argon2 not loading properly.

Am'I forgetting some kind of configuration for this setup to work or is this something more complicated ?

The error output after `mix test`:

```
.05:58:12.350 [error] Process #PID<0.485.0> raised an exception
** (RuntimeError) An error occurred when loading Argon2.
Make sure you have a C compiler and Erlang 20 installed.
If you are not using Erlang 20, either upgrade to Erlang 20 or
use bcrypt_elixir (version 0.12) or pbkdf2_elixir.
See the Comeonin wiki for more information.

    (argon2_elixir 2.4.0) lib/argon2/base.ex:19: Argon2.Base.init/0
    (kernel 6.5.2) code_server.erl:1340: anonymous fn/1 in :code_server.handle_on_load/5
05:58:12.352 [warn] The on_load function for module Elixir.Argon2.Base returned:
{%RuntimeError{
   message: "An error occurred when loading Argon2.\nMake sure you have a C compiler and Erlang 20 installed.\nIf you are not using Erlang 20, either upgrade to Erlang 20 or\nuse bcrypt_elixir (version 0.12) or pbkdf2_elixir.\nSee the Comeonin wiki for more information.\n"
 },
 [
   {Argon2.Base, :init, 0, [file: 'lib/argon2/base.ex', line: 19]},
   {:code_server, :"-handle_on_load/5-fun-0-", 1,
    [file: 'code_server.erl', line: 1340]}
 ]}



  1) test POST /api/users With valid data, a new user is created and returned (MetricusWeb.Api.UserControllerTest)
     apps/metricus_web/test/metricus_web/controllers/user_controller_test.exs:21
     ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Argon2.Base.hash_password/3 is undefined (module Argon2.Base is not available)
     code: conn = post(conn, Routes.user_path(conn, :create), user: @valid_user)
     stacktrace:
       (argon2_elixir 2.4.0) Argon2.Base.hash_password("Password1234567890", <<124, 2, 151, 63, 19, 65, 97, 0, 197, 190, 214, 56, 113, 143, 251, 117>>, [])
       (db 0.1.0) lib/db_schema/user.ex:49: DB.Schema.User.generate_password_hash/1
       (metricus 0.1.0) lib/metricus/user_manager.ex:50: Metricus.UserManager.create_user/1
       (metricus_web 0.1.0) lib/metricus_web/controllers/user_controller.ex:10: MetricusWeb.Api.UserController.create/2
       (metricus_web 0.1.0) lib/metricus_web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: MetricusWeb.Api.UserController.action/2
       (metricus_web 0.1.0) lib/metricus_web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: MetricusWeb.Api.UserController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
       (phoenix 1.5.8) lib/phoenix/router.ex:352: Phoenix.Router.__call__/2
       (metricus_web 0.1.0) lib/metricus_web/endpoint.ex:1: MetricusWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
       (metricus_web 0.1.0) lib/metricus_web/endpoint.ex:1: MetricusWeb.Endpoint.call/2
       (phoenix 1.5.8) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:225: Phoenix.ConnTest.dispatch/5
       test/metricus_web/controllers/user_controller_test.exs:22: (test)
```

Comment: Try `cd ./deps/argon2_elixir && make clean && make`

Comment: for me, the issue was using `iTerm2` on an M1 macbook.    Simply using `terminal` to `rm -rf deps/ _build && mix deps.get && mix deps.compile` fixed the issue.

Comment: @Scott's comment should be the answer.